# Simple selection sort with repeated elements?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

Given a list `x`, I want to sort it with selection sort, and then count the number of swaps made within the sort. So I came out with something like this:

```
count=0
a=0
n=len(x)
while (n-a)>0:
    #please recommend a better way to swap.
    i = (min(x[a:n]))
    x[i], x[a] = x[a], x[i]
    a += 1
    #the count must still be there
    count+=1
print (x)
```

Could you help me to find a way to manage this better? It doesn't work that well.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `x.sort()`?

Comment: I actually plan to add a 'count' feature which will track how many times two numbers in the list swap. So I have to do this manually.

Comment: The count has been fixed, so not to worry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is NOT about repeated elements. Your code doesn't work for lists with all elements distinct, either. Try `x = [2,6,4,5]`.

```
i = (min(x[a:n]))
```

`min()` here gets the **value** of the minimum element in the slice, and then you use it as an **index**, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I get the difference now.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the value of an element, with its location. You must use the index to identify the location.

```
seq = [2,1,0,0]
beg = 0
n = len(seq)

while (n - beg) > 0:
    jdx = seq[beg:n].index((min(seq[beg:n])))            # use the remaining unsorted right
    seq[jdx + beg], seq[beg] = seq[beg], seq[jdx + beg]  # swap the minimum with the first unsorted element.
    beg += 1

    print(seq)

print('-->', seq)
```

- As the sorting progresses, the left of the list [0:beg] is sorted, and the right side [beg:] is being sorted, until completion.
- jdx is the **location** (the index) of the minimum of the remaining of the list (finding the min must happen on the unsorted right part of the list --> [beg:])

Comment: Thanks for the help here. It works now. Probably one of the changes was to instead taking the list for our index, we just select the part without the sorted elements.